# Symfony2 AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException @Route

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

[image]

> AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in classes.php line 2876:
>
> The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

I tried everything I could find on Stack Overflow, GitHub and Google.  Nothing worked.

---

**Lesson learned:** Always check the log files.

```
tail -f app/logs/dev.log
```

Found this:

> ...[Semantical Error] The annotation \"@Route\" in method
>   Ambry\TumorNextAPIBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction()
>   was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a \"use\" statement
>   for this annotation?...

---

I was missing the following use statement(s):

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```

In the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Ambry\TumorNextAPIBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Ambry\BioToolsBundle\Controller\ApplicationController;

class DefaultController extends ApplicationController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="tumornext" )
     * @Method({"GET","POST"})
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lesson learned:** Always check the log files.

```
tail -f app/logs/dev.log
tail -f app/logs/dev.log | grep CRIT
tail -f app/logs/dev.log | grep ERROR
tail -f app/logs/dev.log | grep INFO
```

---

In this case, you're missing use statement(s):

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```